# How to scale 3d Quiver diagrams correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

When quiver is used in a 3d as in 
[this example](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/quiver3d_demo.py)
it is possible only to set the length of all the arrow.
It does not reflect the actual length of the arrows provided.

The argument scale, that works in the 2d case, here does not seems to work.

Is there a way to scale the arrows such that their length reflects the length of the given vector field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weird. It seems the u,v,w just establish direction, and the length parameter effects all the lengths the same. You can't put an array into the length parameter.

As a typical work around, you can just plot each arrow separately:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

print(matplotlib.__version__)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-1, 1, 0.4),
                      np.arange(-1, 1, 0.4),
                      np.arange(-1, 1, 0.4))
x = x.reshape(np.product(x.shape))
y = y.reshape(np.product(y.shape))
z = z.reshape(np.product(z.shape))

scale = 0.02
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.sin(np.pi * z)
lengths = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)

for x1,y1,z1,u1,v1,w1,l in zip(x,y,z,u,v,w,lengths):
    ax.quiver(x1, y1, z1, u1, v1, w1, pivot = 'middle', length=l*0.5)

ax.scatter(x,y,z, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d Quiver]

Comment: Set each length separately is really a work-around, but it seems to work...
Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

just poked around the docs http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html 
does this work for you?

still not obvious that the arrow lengths are right but at least now look 3D

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

print(matplotlib.__version__)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-1, 1, 0.4),
                      np.arange(-1, 1, 0.4),
                      np.arange(-1, 1, 0.4))
scale = 0.02
u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.sin(np.pi * z)

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, pivot = 'middle', arrow_length_ratio = 0.02)
ax.scatter(x,y,z, color = 'black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for your well documented code!
The direction of the arrows are correct but not their length, as usual. Try with a constant function u = 0.001
v = 0.001
w = 0.001
and then with u = 1
v = 1
w = 1
Length is always the same.

Comment: About the bounty it should have been 25 points for Dr Xorile and 25 points for f5r5e5d... Sorry I could not split!

Comment: looks like this is supposed to be fixed in matplotlib 2.0, which has current Release Candidate, and beta version - although I'm not up to building them, can't find a install pkg